# FastAPI TypeError: retreive_job() got multiple values for argument 'id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to build a simple job board using Python, FastAPI and Async sqlalchemy by following the official FastAPI documentation. I'm having some issues regarding retrieving the data from database by `ID`.

The Following is hopefully a minimum reproducible code segment:

**schemas/jobs.py**

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
from datetime import date, datetime


class JobBase(BaseModel):
    title: Optional[str] = None
    company_name: Optional[str] = None
    company_url: Optional[str] = None
    location: Optional[str] = "remote"
    description: Optional[str] = None
    date_posted: Optional[date] = datetime.now().date()

class JobCreate(JobBase):
    title: str
    company_name: str
    location: str
    description: str

class ShowJob(JobBase):
    title: str
    company_name: str
    company_url: Optional[str]
    location: str
    date_posted: date
    description: str

    class Config():
        orm_mode = True
```

**routes/route_jobs.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status
from fastapi import Depends

from db.repository.job_board_dal import job_board
from schemas.jobs import JobCreate, ShowJob
from db.repository.job_board_dal import Job
from depends import get_db

router = APIRouter()

@router.post("/create-job",response_model=ShowJob)
async def create_user(Job: JobCreate, jobs: Job = Depends(get_db)):
    owner_id = 1
    return await jobs.create_new_job(Job, owner_id)

@router.get("/get/{id}")
def retrieve_job_by_id(id:int, job_board = Depends(get_db)):
    #print(type(session))
    job_id = job_board.retrieve_job(job_board, id=id)
    if not job_id:
        HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail=f"Job with id {id} does not exist")
    return job_id
```

**db/repository/job_board_dal.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, query

from schemas.users import UserCreate
from schemas.jobs import JobCreate
from db.models.users import User
from db.models.jobs import Job
from core.hashing import Hasher



class job_board():
    def __init__(self, db_session: Session):
        self.db_session = db_session

    async def register_user(self, user: UserCreate):
        new_user = User(username=user.username,
        email=user.email,
        hashed_password=Hasher.get_password_hash(user.password),
        is_active = False,
        is_superuser=False
        )
        self.db_session.add(new_user)
        await self.db_session.flush()
        return new_user

    
    async def create_new_job(self, job: JobCreate, owner_id: int):
        new_job = Job(**job.dict(), owner_id = owner_id)
        self.db_session.add(new_job)
        await self.db_session.flush()
        return new_job

    def retrieve_job(self, id:int):
        item = self.db_session.query(Job).filter(Job.id == id).first()
        return item
```

**depends.py**

```
from db.session import async_session
from db.repository.job_board_dal import job_board

async def get_db():
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            yield job_board(session)
```

I tried to change the dependency

```
@router.get("/get/{id}")
def retrieve_job_by_id(id:int, id_job: job_board = Depends(get_db)):
    #print(type(session))
    job_id = job_board.retrieve_job(id_job, id=id)
    if not job_id:
        HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND,
        detail=f"Job with id {id} does not exist")
    return job_id
```

it gives me this error `AttributeError: 'AsyncSession' object has no attribute 'query'`.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AsyncSession` class](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_4_20/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py#L48) doesn't declare a `query` property.

You can use [`AsyncSession.get`](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_4_20/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py#L171) the fetch the `Job` record matching a given `id`. This method return `None` if no record is found matching the said `id`.

For example,

```
async def retrieve_job(self, id:int):
    item = await self.db_session.get(Job, id)
    return item
```